# Cacti graphs are not showing any data

Tags: cacti

I am cacti graphs to measure the performance of metrics in ubuntu.

I am not able to see any graphs not blank graphs .

So as a debugging measure , I went to the logger file to see the if the script what I am using is returning values or not.

And yes it returns values .

But the rrd files are not getting updated .

One more thing I noticed is that , the log files are under www-data .

What is happening  and why not the graphs are generating ?

Answer (score 1):

try to change the owner of the installation folder to the user you add

chown -R cacti /var/www/cacti

or just change the owner of the rra and log folder inside the installation folder

chwon -R root:cacti rra/ log/

in my case it will show the graph